# Is "shut up" a noun phrase in "James is getting a bit frustrated shut up here"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> James is getting a bit frustrated **shut up** here, he tries not to show it but I can tell - also, Dumbledore's still got his Invisibility Cloak, so no chance of little excursions.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I feel "shut up" is a noun phrase in this context, meaning *confined*. But I couldn't find it a noun phrase in any dictionary. So, I'm not sure if my understand is correct. How should we understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Shut up here” is a participle phrase, since “shut” is also the past participle of the verb “shut“.  Indeed it means confined.  Someone has shut him up in Hogwarts or wherever he is, so he has been shut up there.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shut_up

Comment: What about 'frustrated' then? I don't understand the syntax of  "getting a bit frustrated shut up".

Comment: Frustrated is just an adjective.  "James is getting a bit frustrated, because he has been shut up here.  He tries not to show it..."